# How was Iron Man able to return at the end of the Avengers movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

At the end of the film,

> Iron Man grabs and steers the nuclear missile through the open portal. At the time just before the suit malfunctions due to atmosphere/cold, his thrusters are firing him towards the Chitauri ship.

and:

> Objects in space continue moving in the same direction unless new force is applied. Wouldn't he have just kept traveling towards the Chitauri ship, or does Earth's gravity somehow exert itself through the portal?

Comment: Wasn't it the blast that pushed him back towards Earth?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The dynamics of the Tesseract/cosmic cube are not easily defined but it appears to alter space-time sufficiently to connect two points in a fashion similar to a wormhole.

> Evidence suggests the gravitational effects of Earth can be felt through the portal. Since the portal was a disruption in space time, it may have had its own gravity well in addition to Earth's gravity. Stark fell at a rate consistent with (or perhaps) even faster than normal gravity.

Comment: Seconding what Thaddeus wrote.  If we make the assumption gravity acts through a wormhole, Stark was well within the Earth's gravitational field when incapacitated.